# PayPal Custom payment pages no longer working

Tags: paypal, checkout

I have a checkout system that has been in place over 5 years. I have another checkout system been in place over 2 years. Both have not changed.

I can also confirm when I demo the custom payment pages through my account it all works.

However when people go through checkout on my site, when they see the new PayPal checkout system, there is no logo at the top and my business name is showing up in text at the top.

I have confirmed that the logo works fine and is hosted on HTTPS.

I contacted PayPal business support and this is the response I got:

> Hi **** Unfortunately, this is the intended behavior. New layout did
>   not support page style parameter. I apologise for the inconvenience
>   caused. Sincerely, Anis Merchant Technical Support PayPal

Can anyone else confirm that PayPal is fazing out custom payment pages? I think this guy is drinking kool aid and like most bad support individuals is providing me incorrect information. However I have been unable to get this idiot to escalate it and get me a real answer.

Especially since I've seen other checkout pages work with a logo at the top.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, looks like `page_style` currently does not work in the new checkout page. As a work-around you can use `image_url` parameter to set your image logo in the checkout page.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why it has stopped working all of a sudden. There was no notice from PayPal about this variable being deprecated. For others, here is the complete list of deprecated vars https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: Old post here I know, but if anyone is interested, image_url doesn't work anymore either. :-(

Answer (score 0):

PayPal deprecated the `page_style` variable in September 2016, as well as the `cpp_logo_image`. The full list of deprecated variables is available here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#deprecated-variables

As user Vimalnath mentionned, you can (still) use the `image_url` parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="https://example.com/myImage.png" />
```

The recommended dimensions of images changed. Whilst the maximal size for `image_url` was 750 x 90 as a banner, the recommended size is (in February 2018) : 150 x 50 px. PayPal now consider the `image_url` as a logo to display in the upper left corner.

I can see that a banner of 750 x 90 is still working on the payment page and will display as a header. Maybe with a smaller logo would PayPal use another layout. I also have not test yet how does a large banner display after the payment was done.

Comment: On PayPal's checkout page a 780x90 banner displays with the right width on my computer. I haven't test however after the login.